# Is it possible to pass List elements as arguments for methods in C#?

Tags: c#

For example, let's say we have a method

```
private void foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
    // do something...
}
```

and some sort of list containing some values

```
List<int> Numbers = new List<int> {
    8, 9, 10
};
```

My question is: Is it possible to pass the whole list as arguments for the declared method if it contains exactly the needed number of elements as the parameters, as in the example?

Something like ...

```
foo(Numbers);

foo(List<int> Numbers);
```

Comment: Have you tried the second one?

Comment: Yes.  Try your second option, also look at the params keyword

Comment: Nope, because the compiler doesn't know how many elements are in any given list, which might seem odd to you because *you* know there is 3 elements in there and there wont be anything other than those three elements, but the compiler can't/ doesn't assume that and there's no syntactic sugar to tell it just do that, you'll need/ want to do `Foo(Numbers[0], Numbers[1], Numbers[2])`, you can see it leads to a compile time error [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ErVBc)

Comment: @MindSwipe if you remove the `foo(List<int> Numbers);` in your example and place it in the method below, like `private static void Foo(List<int> numbers)`, then it will compile correctly. It will also carry over the list with it's contents. Perhaps not the same as passing over it's contents as arguments, but it can archieve the same effect